# how should I whitelist an ipv6 in azure db

Tags: database, azure, ipv6, whitelist

I have a PostgreSQL DB in azure and when I want to whitelist my IP address I get the error:

> "IP address must be valid IP v4"

. But I have ipv6 address.[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Ts8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message said "IP address must be valid ip v4 address", you can not set it with ip v6 address.

You can run this command in you CMD window to get you IvP4 address:

```
ipconfig /all
```

For example:
[image]

Fore details, you also can reference this document: [Create and manage firewall rules for Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Single Server using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-manage-firewall-using-portal).

Hope this helps.